# migrating local dev site to live site with no downtime

Tags: migration

i know the issue of migrating a local dev site to a live site has been discussed extensively, but i'm wondering how to do this without any downtime.

i'm working on a local copy of my live site to integrate a new theme.  being as some of the theme admin settings are different (upload logo, widgets, menus, templates, etc), i think the only way to make these changes final are after migrating my site, so i'm thinking i'll have to upload my new theme when i'm done with the local version, and then rush to change the admin settings after the fact on my live site.

previously, i've done this by creating an additional wp install on my live server, made all final changes, and then pointed the top level domain to the new install.  i'm unable to do it this way based on how the hosting & domain is setup @ this hosting (the domain is managed by a 3rd party, and it may take a few days for them to point the domain to a new server - honestly i don't even want to have to deal with this with them).

wondering if there is another way to do this?  or something i'm missing?

thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you install a new wp next to your existing install? 
I assume you can.

Your only argument is changing the domain would take long.

If you do a new install in a subfolder. And when finished just edit your `.htaccess` file accordingly.

It should be close to immediately.

Comment: You should read this article on WP.org before attempting this to cover your bases: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Comment: thanks so much guys.  would this work in my new install's config.php instead of editing .htaccess?

`
define('WP_HOME','http://mytopleveldomain.com/mynewinstallfolder/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://mytopleveldomain.com');
`

Comment: That could most likely work aswell. Have not tested that before.

Comment: being as the domain is external from the hosting (pointed via dns type A record), could the modification to .htaccess or config.php cause problems?

Comment: has nothing to do with eachother. .htacces comes into play when the visitor is already on your server.